# In dynamic typing the existing variable's ID isn't changing in python

Tags: python, dynamic-typing

```
value = 10

print(value, id(value), type(value))

value = "100"

print(value, id(value), type(value))
```

Output :

```
10 1383004224 <class 'int'>
       
100 21775456 <class 'str'>
```

when I rerun the above code the ID of the TYPE `str` is changing but the ID of the TYPE `int` is not changing why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`small integer caching` Python caches small integers, which are integers between -5 and 256. So all you need is used for your tests numbers more then 256 or less then -5.

Comment: Thank for you answer sir

Comment: Accepted sir :)

Comment: Glad to help you!

Answer (score 1):

The id returned by Python"s built-in [`id()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) function returns the memory-address.

Python uses caching (for immutable types) as explained on AskPython's article [Using the id() function in Python](https://www.askpython.com/python/id-function-in-python)

The phenomenon you are experiencing with your (small) integers is described on *Real Python*'s article [**Small Integer Caching**](https://realpython.com/lessons/small-integer-caching/):

> What is *small integer caching*? Python caches small integers, which are integers between -5 and 256. These numbers are **used so frequently** that it’s better for performance to already have these objects available. So these integers will be assigned at startup. Then, each time you refer to one, you’ll be referring to an object that already exists.